# How to get result separators as | in the left join of the mysql on equal?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table adherent and utilisateur.

```
Table : adherent     

adherent_id (auto increment) statut
204                          1
446                          0
447                          0
504                          1

Table : utilisateur

utilisateur_id  adherent_id  statut
1            204|446      1
2            446|204      1
3            204          1
4            446          1

'SELECT `adherent`.* FROM `adherent` 
                    As adherent 
                    left join 
                    `utilisateur` as utilisateur on adherent.`adherent_id` = utilisateur.`adherent_id` REGEXP "[[:<:]]204[[:>:]]" 

                    WHERE `adherent`.`adherent_id` = 204 AND 
                          `adherent`.`statut` = 1 AND 
                          `utilisateur`.`statut` = 1 AND 
                          `utilisateur`.`reviewer_id` = 0'
```

How to get the statut = 1 of both the table adherent and utilisateur.

Comment: You aren't yet clear what you want to do. Do you want to insert or retrieve? If it's about retrieving data, how do you expect the separator should work? Share the scenario.

Comment: maybe this will help: `SELECT t.*,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(s.adherent_id)
 FROM utilisateur s 
WHERE t.adherent_id = s.adherent_id AND s.statut = 1) AS mixedValue
FROM adherent t
WHERE t.statut = 1`